# Python:Hide Password

Tags: python

everytime it shows my PASS in this way cmd 'PASS XXXXXX'.How can I stop it showing my PASS? Here is my code.Everyone knows how to do it?

```
import os, sys, string
import poplib
import getpass
host = "pop3.163.com"

username = raw_input('Username:')

pp = poplib.POP3(host)

pp.set_debuglevel(1)

pp.user(username)

pp.pass_(getpass.getpass())

action =""

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
   action = sys.argv[1]

if action == 'stat':
   ret = pp.stat()
   print ret
  # sys.exit()

else:
 print "I dont know this command"
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not a result of calling `pp.set_debuglevel(1)`? Do you still see it without setting it or setting it to 0?

Comment: @FatalError Can you post that as an answer, so OP can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simply, it's because you've asked the POP3 lib to give you debugging output. Some of what it's included appears to be the password that's being sent to the server. To avoid this, you should simply omit your log level set (the documentation says the default level is 0 -> no output), or explicitly set it to 0.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `getpass` you need to save it in a variable or else, in the command line at least, it will print out the password:

```
>>> import getpass
>>> getpass.getpass()
Password: 
'password'
>>> pword = getpass.getpass()
Password: 
>>> pword
'password'
```

Comment: This is an artifact of executing in the interactive shell -- the result is printed as any other value except `None` would be.